# about tables relationships in ms access and forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, relational-database

I have a relational database in access, but I have issues joining tables (first time doing a relational database). I did three queries: on first I got costumers and orders information, on second one I got products and quantities. On third one, I got issues information based in first and second queries with some issues table fields.

Then I did a form with query costumer data and a subform with products information (quantities) and I need a issue form. I added a yes/no field from issues table, and when I tick it in subform, I want to be displayed a issues form to type data issues for each record.

The best I could do was joining "identifier" from "incidencias" table to "identifier" to "pedidos" table. I got what I wanted, but I got the issues form fields locked and greyedo out when I tried to entry data, maybe because I did forms based just in queries (I read that searching in google). when I did the form based only in tables, I got serveral errors and the same field information for all records.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like form bound to a non-updatable query. What errors when forms bound to just tables?

Comment: when I try to join "pedido" in "productos-pedidos" table to "identificador" from "incidencias" table I get a warning that shows "no unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table". Should I create a intermediate table to join "productos pedidos" table and "incidencias" table? Thanks again, June.

Comment: PEDIDO field alone is not a key since duplicate values are allowed. I expect same is true of IDENTIFICADOR in INCIDENCIAS. Joining on primary keys results in a 1-to-1 relationship. Probably not what you want. You have compound keys established which should probably just be compound index to prevent duplicate pairs. I avoid compound keys. What is INCIDENCIAS table for?

Comment: INCIDENCIAS table stores issues during the production and should be related to an order code, and to a product from that order. For example: for the order nº1 It should be made product nº 1 and product nº 2. When making product nº 2, an issue occurs and that issue should be stored in INCIDENCIAS table, keeping: order nº, cliente, product information, issue hour, etc. I made a form to link to "PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS" table. I link both forms by a "incidencias"yes/no field in PRODUCTOS -PEDIDOS table. When I tick, that field in a product record the form pops up and I must complete it.

Comment: Seems to me ID in PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS should be primary key and that value saved to INCIDENCIAS. Use a subform for INCIDENCIAS that links to PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS. If you want PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS as a subform in Datasheet with INCIDENCIAS sitting next to it, review https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp. No need to duplicate CLIENTE, IDENTIFICADOR, CODIGO into INCIDENCIAS as they can be retrieved in query linking tables for report output or report/subreport arrangement.

Comment: If you really want compound key then subform Master/Child links properties must have compound links - PEDIDO to INDENTIFICADOR and CODIGO to CODIGO PRODUCTO. PRODUCTO field need not be in PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS because it can be retrieved in query linking tables.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but I need to show the INCIDENCIAS subform only when a product cause issues during production and hidding that form if there aren`t issues. Is there any way to do this?  as INCIDENCIAS subform is embedded in PRODUCTOS-PEDIDOS subform, I don't know how could I do it. Is there any way to create a form linked not as subform? I figured out using the check INCIDENCIAS field of the PRODUCTOS-PEDIDOS form to link INCIDENCIAS form could work, but I got the troubles I described on first post

Comment: That would mean opening an independent form and passing ID to form when it opens. Gets complicated especially if intent is to create a new INCIDENCIAS record. Why does it matter if form is displayed? Shouldn't user have opportunity to enter record? Your question is related to design, not programming and not really appropriate for SO.